# Conditional statement for characters in a string

Tags: ruby, string

I am writing a simple survey, which collects user inputs and assigns them to class attributes. One attribute is `gender`. I want to split the user input into an array, take the first letter, and decide whether the gender is male or female. For example, if the input string starts with an `"f"` (for female) or `"g"` (for girl) or `"w"` (for woman), the gender attribute should return `"her"`.

Here is what I got:

```
puts "What is #{responder.fname}'s' gender?" 
len = [gets.chomp]

responder.gender =
if len[0] == "f" or len[0] =="w" or len[0] =="g" 
        responder.gender = "her" 

            elsif len[1] = "u" #<= for "gUy"
            responder.gender = "his"

        else
            responder.gender = "his"
end
```

The attribute keeps returning `"his"` regardless of my conditional tests. I can't figure out why my conditional statement is not working.

Comment: If `gets.chomp => "fCarla"`, `len = ["fCarla"]`, so `len[0] => "fCarla"`, but you want `len[0] => "f"`.  You need to change `len = [gets.chomp]` to `len = gets.chomp`.  Also, you need to remove all `responder.gender =` except for the first one.

Comment: Splitting a string into an array is not necessary for checking something about the first character. By writing that you want to split, you are excluding better ways to fulfill your goal.

Comment: @CarySwoveland ahhhh! got it.  So [gets.chomp] will capture the entire string into an array. Instead I can ask for the [0] from the actual input. Thank you so much!

Comment: Note also that `elsif len[1] = "u"; "his"` has no effect, because `else` returns `"his"`.  Try this: `len=gets.chomp; responder.gender = case len[0]; when "f", "w", "g"; "her"; else "his"; end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Assign Value of a Case Expression

You can simplify your code a lot by recalling that in Ruby, every expression returns a value. Given that you already have a Responder object that has a setter method for gender, like:

```
require 'ostruct'
responder = OpenStruct.new
```

you can just match the first character of each response and return the appropriate string. For example:

```
responder.gender = case gets.downcase.chomp
                   when /^f/ then 'female'
                   when /^m/ then 'male'
                   else 'other'
                   end
```

There are certainly other ways to do this, but this seems clear and straightforward to me, and clearly communicates the intent of the code. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find more info on the '    /^*/' operator(s) you used?

Comment: @DimaNYC You can start with the [Regexp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html) core module for information about Ruby-specific implementation details. I also recommend reading books like O'Reilly's [Introducing Regular Expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920012337.do) to learn more about regular expressions in general.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution, which is a built-in method that ships with Ruby v1.9.1+. This method is called `'start_with'`. It does exactly what I needed, by taking the first character(s) of a string `"foo"` and comparing it to a passed argument `("f")`. Here is what it looks like:

```
x = "foo"
if x.start_with?("f") 
puts "match"
else 
puts "bar"
end
```